# .Html JQuery does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer

I have some functions to translate my application into the language of the client connected to it.

They are:

```
function Traduzione(Lingua, pagina) {       // traduce la frase nella lingua passata
    $.ajax({
        url: '/assets/Traduzione/language' + Lingua + '.xml',           // file xml della lingua in cui tradurre
        success: function (xml) {
            xmlTranslate = xml;
            $(xml).find(pagina).each(function () {                          // trova la frase nel file

                var id = $(this).attr('id');            // assegna l'id trovato
                var text = $(this).html();                  // assegna il testo trovato
                if ($("." + id).is('input[type="submit"]') == true) {   // controlla se l'oggetto è un pulsante
                    $("." + id).val(text);      // se si, inserisce il testo in val
                } else {
                    $("." + id).html(text);         // altrimenti in html
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

function TraduzioneParola(Lingua, idoggetto) {          // traduce il testo dell'oggetto nella lingua passata

    var text = $("#" + idoggetto + "", xmlTranslate).html();    // assegna il testo tradotto

    return text;            // ritorna il testo tradotto
}
```

These work in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE I return the error: 
"Failed to retrieve the property 'replace' a reference to null or undefined" 
This is because the node is not passed, and then a replace on an undefined object.

you can fix the error? 
Many thanks for your reply. 
dave

Comment: Can you tel me the order in which the Jquery files are included?

Comment: what is the stack of the error?

Comment: SCRIPT5007: Impossibile recuperare la proprietà 'replace' di un riferimento nullo o non definito File: jquery-1.10.2.min.js, riga: 5, colonna: 26770

Comment: the line of the error is: 

var text = $ (this) html (); // Assign the found text

Comment: translate the stack: 
"SCRIPT5007: Failed to retrieve the property 'replace' a reference to null or undefined File: jquery-1.10.2.min.js, line 5, Column: 26770"

Comment: @Dave how about doing a google search for `SCRIPT5007`?

Answer (score 0):

try to add to your code this

```
// file XML della lingua in cui tradurre
$.ajax({ url: '/assets/Traduzione/language' + Lingua + '.xml',           
         contentType: "text/xml",
         success: function (xml) {
         }
       });
```